# C++: Store mapping between old int handles and new ones

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dictionary, mapping

I have an array with struct elements. I need to remove some elements from the array and store mapping between old values ​​and new ones.

I.e, fill std::map, the key of which is the old index of the element from the array and Its value is the new index from the array. (Because when values ​​are removed from the vector, it is shifted to the left.)

I will show what I need with an example:

```
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6
arr0 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
        0  1  2  3  4  5
arr1 = {a, b, c, e, f, g} //after delete d

map[0]=0 // a
map[1]=1 // b
map[2]=2 // c
map[4]=3 // e
map[5]=4 // f
map[6]=5 // g
```

Help me to implement this.
I have an array from structures:

```
 struct HalfEdgeHandle { int64_t index = -1; };

 std::vector<HalfEdgeHandle> halfEdges = {};
```

I need to remove the elements of the array which halfEdges[i].index == -1

Comment: Did you ask this exact same question just a little while ago? I remember seeing it almost verbatim before. If you did, then please don't do that in the future. Improve the question you have instead.

Comment: This question was asked, and then deleted.  Many valid comments have now gone down the memory hole.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of *your own* attempt.

Comment: There even was an answer that may have solved the problem. The actual problem is no clearer now if anything its worse because there were more details in the comments.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Are you interested in original location of each characters? in your example the location of more characters are changing after shifting all elements to the left. Also shifting all elements after each delete is not cheap (O(n) in worst case). A better approach is to swap them with last element and decrease the pointer that points to end of list. One important point is that in this case you may need to consider whether the picked element is the last element of the valid members or not.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I have understood your question, this should be the solution:

```c++
struct HalfEdgeHandle {};
std::vector<HalfEdgeHandle> halfEdges = {};

// Here store your data into the vector

std::map<int, int> map;
std::vector<HalfEdgeHandle> copy;
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < halfEdges.size(); i++)
{
    if(halfEdges[i].index != -1)
    {
        copy.append(halfEdges[i]);
        map[i] = j++;
    }
}
```

`copy` should be the `std::vector` without any element which has `index == -1`. `map` will look like as you described.

Let me point out two things:

- Consider changing the `map` and `copy` variable names into something that makes more sense in your code
- Consider changing how you store the previous indexes and the new ones. I would swap the key-value pair, so you have continuous indexes. If you do this, you can use `std::vector` instead of `std::map` (I usually tend to avoid using `std::map` when not mandatory).

Comment: @Torney Perfect! Please, see also the last two things I've just added. Then, if you are satisfied, could you approve the answer and upvote it?

Comment: thanks, I'd love to upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @Torney oh, I see. You should be able at least to mark this as the answer (just click on the tick on the left. This helps me with the reputation and everyone that will have the same question as yours. If you don't want to or if you can't, never mind!